# How to prompt an alert message when a user forgot to choose a radio button and straight away clicking a proceed command button using java?

Tags: alert

I have created this interface menu and my problem is I don't know how to show or prompt a message if a user forgot to choose a radio button and straight away clicking the 'PILIH' button.

Which is I made it for proceeding to the next process. Here is part of the code for your reference as it is already fine with the radio button selection.

```
private void pilihButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (LuasBulatanRB.isSelected()){
        this.dispose();
        new KiraBulatanGUI().setVisible(true);
    }
    if (LuasSegiTigaRB.isSelected()){
        this.dispose();
        new KiraSegiTigaGUI().setVisible(true);
    }
    if (LuasSegiEmpatRB.isSelected()){
        this.dispose();
        new KiraSegiEmpatTepatGUI().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R83Oo.png)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Require field validator.Or use JQuery.

$('#element').click(function() { if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); } });